# Flexbox columns align two top, two mid and two bottom without container & undesired gaps CSS only

Tags: css, flexbox

This is a setup for my amp portait pages(just fyi).

Setup: For a flexbox who puts the items by default at bottom in column format.
Lets say i have 5 elements as an example and have 3 classes: top, mid & bottom(by default not needed as .container is just-content:flex-end).

```
h2,h3 { padding:0; margin:0; border-top:1px solid gray }
.flex { height: 100%; min-height:460px; 
    display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; flex-direction: column; width:320px; }

.top{ }
.mid { }
.btm { }

<div class="flex">
<h2 class="top">Top Heading 2</h2><p class="top">Top para</p>
<h3 class="mid">Mid Heading 3</h3><p class="mid">mid para</p>
<h3 class="btm">Btm Heading 3</h3><p class="btm">bottom para</p>
</div>
```

Problem: What should be .top, .mid & .bottom such that they come  *top:goes to top(without undesired margins), mid: exact mid(not mid of left space)* & any pending items at bottom.

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkv9zxdt/) for this.

Have messed around 2 days to fix, but one or other thing goes wrong, hence finally asking for help.

Comment: This should work: `.flex { align-content: space-between } .flex>* { flex: 1 }` => basically: move child element to the edges and/or center vertically and allow them to grow to fill the available space. With `flex-direction: row` you would use `justify-content` instead of `align-content`.

Comment: @RenevanderLende im only looking for flex-direction column solution as row one does not fit my setup

Comment: I saw, just mentioning `justify-content` to be complete.